# Photoshop Scripting without Knowing Any programming Knowledge?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

is there a way to Photoshop Scripting  without Knowing Any programming Knowledge. I want to know if any visual algorithm to code conversion that will make easy for photoshop scripting or any guide to make photoshop script easily. plz help i want to automate certain task

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Are you not able to use actions for what you're trying to do? That doesn't require any coding knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you were hoping for but **no, you can't do Photoshop scripting without (a little) programming knowledge**.

Scripting in Photoshop is done in [ExtendScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExtendScript):

> It is a dialect of the ECMAScript 3 standard and therefore similar
> to JavaScript and ActionScript.

So some basic knowledge of JavaScript is needed and it also takes a little effort to understand the [object model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_model) available in Adobe's applications.

That said, **many tasks in Photoshop can be automated using [Actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) instead.**

Comment: note that Adobe is abandoning ExtendScript in favour of the new UXP framework and old scripts won't work soon — so I guess no real point of learning the old thing now

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, I didn't know! Been trying to find out what is going to happen with ExtendScript (since ESTB was abandoned) without success.

Comment: it'll just disappear :( and all existing scripts and panels will turn into pumpkins

Comment: I had a quick look at UXP. It's nice that it has become so accessible to make your own panels, but the API still seems limited or am I missing something?

Comment: It is, yes. and it's not clear how much time will it take to bring it to the level of the JSX. One of the reasons I cry at nights :D

Comment: Relax, I'm pretty sure *you* won't turn into a pumpkin.  If you use scripting for advanced stuff, can't you just keep using the current version of PS until UXP improves? I'm often underwhelmed by new versions anyway. Didn't start using PS 2022 until yesterday because it had many bugs and didn't work with my GTX 1070 before.

Comment: personally yes, but I also code as hobby — and sell the result... for example ARM-native Photoshop (for M1 Macs) has only UXP already (I wonder the release was in a hurry because of that..). And the idea that I have to rewrite all my scripts and panels from zero for the new framework but also for some time they will have only 50% features is depressing!

Comment: @joojaa all CC apps are getting the UXP support at different moments: XD was the first one, if I'm not mistaken PS was the next... not sure when other apps getting it

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy no what im saying theres some configuration error in our enterprise licensing that makes it impossible for me to log to adobe.io thus makes it a bit hard to do anything.